# Oracle ocorre problema de connect identifier is too long

Tags: php, oracle

Eu tenho o seguinte problema, primeiramente a configuração do meu PC.

> SO: Fedora 20
>
> PHP 5.5
>
> Oracle Instant Client: 11.2.0.4.0

Eu tento me conectar via configurações do arquivo tnsnames.ora e ocorre o seguinte erro

```
ORA-12169: TNS:Net service name given as connect identifier is too long
```

Para conectar no PHP utilizo a extensão [oci8](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.oci8.php) com a versão `oci8-2.0.6`

A string de fato é grande, mas no SQL Developer conecta normalmente.

Comment: É possivel diminuir essa string? na[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/net12150.htm#ORA-12169]( documentação) fala de um limite de 255 caracteres

Comment: Pior que não dá, pois é necessario a redundância, pois são muitos usuários se conectando ao mesmo tempo

Comment: Acho que achei o problema, depois de muita busca, o problema, aparentemente é que o arquivo foi criado no windows onde possui o CR/LF e o linux só o LF, basta converter para arquivo padrão no Linux e funciona corretamente.

Comment: Igor, sugiro que responda você mesmo à sua própria pergunta. Pode facilitar as coisas caso alguém passe por um problema parecido e venha a se deparar com esta questão. Aproveitando para deixar minha opinião valendo apenas 2 centavos, acredito que isso é um bug. No mínimo o código de erro deveria ser outro, e considero mais adequados os ORA-12154 e ORA-12162.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que achei o problema, depois de muita busca, o problema, aparentemente é que o arquivo foi criado no windows onde possui o CR/LF e o linux só o LF, basta converter para arquivo padrão no Linux e funciona corretamente.